# Getx package GetConnect() how to add body to get request?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I am using Getx package for my api calls, the object GetConnect(). I want to add a body to a get request but I could not find any parameters for it.

```
  final connection = GetConnect();
var response =
        await connection.get(url, headers: header);
```

I want to add a body like this:

```
var response =
            await connection.get(url, headers: header, body: body);
```

but there is no parameter like that. How can I do that?